# identifying leading line space - shell script

Tags: linux, shell, centos, ubuntu-14.04, text-processing

I have a sample file like below. There are leading line spaces. Is there a way to detect them and print the exact line number which contains the line space using shell script?

```
test space at back 
 test space at front
TAB at end  
    TAB at front
```

Answer (score 0):

grep can find blanks with [:blank:] and the beginning of a line with ^ (regex)

`grep -n` will print the line number

try `grep -n '^[[:blank:]]' filename`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me !
if grep -n '^ ' config.js /dev/null >&2; then
     echo "$0: Leading spaces identified above; aborting" >&2
    exit 1
fi